# play 2.0 maintain data in page refresh

Tags: playframework-2.0, session-variables, browser-cache

It's my first time using the play framework and I am a relatively junior developer so hopefully this question doesn't make me sound too stupid:

I have a form where users can change their personal data, and under the form is a bunch of items "recommended" for the user.

If the user clicks submit and there's an error in the form, the page will refresh and tell the user what is wrong.  So far it works, but whenever there's an error, the page will look into the database and fetch all the user's recommended items again and use it to render the page.

Is there a better way so I m not hitting the db over and over again?  I know you can prob use sessions or caching, but are they good alternatives?  Basically if i have a lot of information on a page, and want to reload the same page again, what is the best way to retain all these information?

AJAX is not an option for now as many of users are on IE6.

thanks!

Comment: Please USE ajax, only to filter out those IE6 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, caching mechanism is a good option, actually that's the perfect usage case for cache.

Probably recommendation doesn't need to display 'live' data , they are just a suggestion and most of users don't follow it strictly.

It's enough if you'll cache it for an example for 600 seconds, on the model level. This time is long enough for filling the form, so even if user will make 10 tries of form sending it will take recommendation without touching the DB.

Finally you can just invalidate the cache entry after successful form sending, so next page will fetch new items and will store it for next 10 minutes.

Note: session is NOT good option as it just has limited size.